# Is there a limit of MAX number of rows when uploading a CSV to Big Query?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have a colleague trying to upload a CSV file to Big Query using the web interface.  The file size is less than 100KB and has 1352 rows.  It appears that only the first 1000 rows are getting uploaded to Big Query.

I did not see any sort of row limit listed on this page - https://developers.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery.  Is 1000 rows really the limit for uploading a CSV?  Does the same limit apply to gsutil when uploading to Big Query?  Is there a way to configure that limit per project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just heard back from my colleague, appears to be a user error. He queried the list that he just uploaded and the query by default had "LIMIT 1000" at the end of the SQL text. When he removed the LIMIT, he was able to confirm all content was uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you managed to solve the problem.

For reference, the web interface allows uploads of up to 10 MB. For the restrictions at the API level, see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy.